# Basic HTML Why can't I center my nav bar?

Tags: html, navigation, center

I just can't seem to get my navigation bar, and the logo in the middle, to be in the centre of the page.

What am I doing wrong? Is the container the problem?

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
      <div id="header" class="clearfix">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
            <li>
              <div class="headerimage"><img src="images/header.png" alt="Richi Rich Logo"></div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end header-->

  <div class="footer"> Richard Medhurst © 2013</div>
</div>

</body>
    </html>
```

My .css style sheet is here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/j7r373e5qwx0vji/style.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the width of your `ul` from 1200px to 400px

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/LstNS/38/

```
#header ul { 
  margin:0 auto; 
  width:400px; 
  list-style: none; 
  *zoom: 1; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vector. But I would like to keep the logo in the middle.

If I change the ul from 1200px to 400px it looks like this.

http://postimg.org/image/wa2gc5ec3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work on displays of 1200px wide and above. Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/V2UGb/)**</kbd>

```
#header li { 
  display:inline-block;
  height: 160px; /* Height of the image */
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -3px;

}
.headerimage img {
  margin-top: -55px;
  /* For demo purpose */
  width: 500px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

Comment: That put everything in the center, thanks. But now the links "Home, Music, etc. aren't on the yellow line anymore - only my logo is. 

Is there a way to bring the letters up?

http://s24.postimg.org/8o3hpmadx/Untitled_1.jpg

Comment: Genius! You totally rock man! :) Thanks a bunch. That was driving me mad. Could you please tell me what I was doing wrong, so I can avoid it in the future? Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, you did nothing wrong,  just missed a few things, I've put `height` on list items to match the image height and verticaly aligned them to top, added margins etc.

Comment: OK, thanks again:)
I have one more question, if it's not too much trouble.

I updated the jsfiddle that you made with my current code. 
I'm trying to get the layout to look like this : http://postimg.org/image/kpwxr25lv/

But I'm having lots of trouble moving that horizontal line to the center, and a bit lower.
I think I have all my margins and paddings messed up. :\

Comment: You didn't post the link for the updated fiddle, insert your whole code in the fiddle and then tell me what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey - sorry, you're right. I was confused with the fiddle that the user below had posted. Here's my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/richirich/UtZGa/
This is what it looks like on Chrome, when I run it from my PC : http://postimg.org/image/kpwxr25lv/
I'd like to lower the horizontal bar and put it in the middle. I don't understand why it's stuck to the first youtube video :\

Comment: You didn't post whole CSS code so...try to replace `<hr>` with `<div class="hr"></div>` and add this CSS `.hr { background: #888; width: 600px; height: 2px; margin: 50px auto 30px; }`.

Comment: Oh :S I thought I did paste the whole CSS code.
I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. :\ I somehow can't move the second youtube video (defined by .youtube2 in the CSS file). I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I thought that using the margin command would be enough to move things around, but it doesn't seem to work all the time. 
Could it be that something is taking up space and blocking the other objects from moving?

Comment: Is your site on localhost or live server?

Comment: Yes it's on localhost, on my PC at the moment. I haven't uploaded it yet to the liveserver.

Comment: Ah! I figured something out. My mistake was that I was using "margin-right" (etc). to position the different boxes of text and videos on the page. I should have been using padding, because the objects don't push each other around anymore now. ^^